# Use twitter share buttons as a popup in desktop, and in-app in mobile

Tags: twitter

i need to put a tweet button that in mobile, opens in the app of twitter (if it is installed), and in desktop opens a popup.

I tried with the different buttons in the docs, but any of them works in both cases, for example, the web intent, works in mobile, but in desktop, opens a new tab, and if I use `window.open()` then display a popup up, but doesn't work in mobile.

And I need that the button have a custom design!

Thanks!